# tvOS: How do I make a circular button that still gets a shadow when focused?

Tags: uibutton, uikit, tvos

**Update:** As of WWDC 2017, tvOS supports non-roundrect buttons. [Here's a link to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/209/?time=1080).

**Original question:**

On tvOS, the system-type `UIButton` gets a neat shadow effect when it's in focus.

I'd like to get this effect, but with a rounded `UIButton`. So far, I've tried the following:

1. I've tried rounding the corners with the ol' `layer.cornerRadius` trick - but this doesn't work; the buttons are round but they do not lift off the view when focused (because they're clipping to bounds):

   ```
   button.layer.cornerRadius = button.size.width / 2.0
   button.clipsToBounds = true
   ```
2. I've tried setting a circular background image - but now there's a weird background color or shadow appearing behind the buttons:

   ```
   button.setBackgroundImage(myCircularImage, forState: .Normal)
   ```

   Here's what Option 2 looks like (note: the red button is currently focused):
   [image: Red button is focused, background shadows are weird]

Is there something else I can try with `UIButton(type: .System)` to get the Focus Engine's shadow effect for free? Or do I need to write something more custom for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I spoke with Apple engineers at the tvOS talks in Seattle this month - there is currently no way to get the system-standard Focus behaviors (parallax, motion effects, shine, etc) for round UIButtons - which is a bummer!

They recommended that I either change the design, or write my own focus/parallax/motion effects for the UIButton. I'm not eager to write my own - it's probably not possible to fully replicate the system-standard effects, and when the platform changes in the future, the custom effects will probably look dated.

**Update**: I've written up a blog post and included sample code for accomplishing this effect: http://www.devsign.co/notes/custom-focus-effects-in-tvos

**Update #2**: As of WWDC 2017, tvOS supports non-roundrect buttons! [Here's Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/209/?time=1080).

[image: finished product]

Comment: could you look at code blocks in your article? some part is not considered as code

Comment: and therefore `Set` in CustomFocusEffectCoordinator is missing code part in `<...>`

Comment: and `CustomFocusableButton` does not conform to `CustomFocusableViewType` in Swift 2.2

Comment: Thanks for catching the code block formatting thing! I've fixed the markdown on that article. If the source isn't making sense, you can also check out the repo here: https://github.com/bryanjclark/devsign-CustomFocusEffect

Comment: Eeh, and how did I miss that link :/ Thanks :)

Comment: Good job! But how about make a circle button with a background image?

Comment: @StijnWesterhof `CustomFocusableButton` is a subclass of `UIButton`, so you can use the `UIButton` APIs to do it!

Comment: @bryanjclark Do you have any sample code for the rounded buttons in tvOS 11+? I have searching everywhere in the Apple site, hoping to find the source code for the WWDC example, but nothing. Actually I would just love to have my  UIImageView expanded when focused with round corners.

Comment: Even using Apple's code it seem that the shadows are always rectangular on tvOS 13.4 (I didn't tested in other versions). Did this ever worked on tvOS 11?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this effect by utilizing the focus engine and determining when your button is in focus, and applying the proper transformations on it.

I like to achieve a similar effect on my views by applying a scaling transformation on the view, and also apply a shadow effect like this. Remember to implement rasterization on the layer for performance:

```
if context.nextFocusedView == accountAddOkButton {
    context.nextFocusedView!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1)
    let layer = context.nextFocusedView!.layer
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1)
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    layer.shadowRadius = 12.0
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.80
    layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: layer.bounds).CGPath
 }
```

EDIT:

Be sure to take a look at apple's documentation for creating Parallax Artwork if you wan't to achieve the same effect they use throughout the home screen https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/CreatingParallaxArtwork.html